Ajax url Data result
Im trying to make a single view crud operation on ASP.NET MVC
and having trouble getting data from ajax call and display it on a input field.
here the json actionresult

heres the ajax call

heres the data result

how can i extract that data and display it to an input field
i try this but nothing workds


Could you pls share the codes in words instead of screenshots. We can't copy your code snippet from the screenshots and then test them.

According to your codes, you return the json return Json(new { data = objplan });, and your planid is not inside a list of objects.
So you should could directly use the data.data.planid, it will return the right value, more details, you could refer to below codes:
ASP.NET CORE:
    public IActionResult GetPlan(int id) {
        Plan objplan = new Plan { planID = 1, Price =1  };
        return Json(new { data = objplan });
    }

    public class Plan {

        public int planID { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }
    }

Ajax:
    function getplanbyid(planid) { 
    
        $.ajax({

            url: "/home/getplan?id=" + planid,
            type:"get",
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data.data.planID);
            }
        });
    }

Result:

